# Cypress: How do I overwrite the visit command to always attempt to dismiss a popup after the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, cypress

Cypress overwrite: I would like to overwrite the existing `visit` command so that it still operates as is, but will attempt to dismiss a popup **after** the visit has successfully executed.

The popup is something we have very little control over and it appears after you login. Seeing as we're bypassing the login screen and logging in programmatically, we'll see the popup when we navigate to any page. The insufficient code I currently have:

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url, options) => {
originalFn(url, options);

cy.get("body").then($body => {
  if ($body.find("[text='Got it']").length > 0) { 
     cy.contains("Got it", { matchCase: false }).click();
  }
});
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by overwriting `cy.visit()` command. Try this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url, options) => {
  originalFn(url, options);
  // make sure to add a return here!
  return cy.get('body').then($body => {
    if ($body.find("[text='Got it']").length > 0) {
      cy.contains('Got it', { matchCase: false }).click();
    }
  });
});
```

source: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Overwrite-visit-command